# SSRS Exported PDF and TIF report render differently than in the report viewer

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm seeing basically the same issue described **[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ccb56dec-250b-4b67-a3ed-74d8bbb446d4)**

I have a table that starts in the middle of the first page, and, depending on the size of the table, it should wrap onto the next page. This behaves fine when using the viewer, but when exporting to a pdf or tif image, things are displayed differently. Instead of starting on the first page and wrapping onto the second, it moves the entire table to start on the second page, leaving lots of ugly white-space on the first page. I've made sure that KeepTogether is false on the table, and there is no header/footer on the page (so it can't extend beyond the page's width).

Has anyone seen this problem, or know of a solution/troubleshooting steps?

Thanks!

Comment: How many rows in the table that is incorrectly placed on the 2nd page?

Comment: There are 23 total rows in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by re-creating the report(s) in question using the Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 (instead of 2005). Don't know what was different in the re-created report, but it works properly now.