# Entire Table is pushed to the next page when rendering a SSRS 2005 Report (as .pdf) in SSRS 2008

Tags: pdf, ssrs-2008, render, reportingservices-2005

I have a SSRS 2005 report that I'm rendering in SSRS 2008 as a .pdf. The report contains (among other things) a table that's very simple: header row, details, no footer, no aggregation, no grouping, keep together = false, pageBreakAtStart = false, pageBreakAtEnd = false, repeatHeaderOnNewPage = true. I resized the table to be much narrower than the body of the report just to be sure it wasn't extending beyond the bounds of the report, pushing everything down. But, no matter what I try, if some of the detail rows in that table would need to be pushed to the next page, then the ENTIRE TABLE is pushed to the next page, not just the extra rows.

**So my question is: Is there a workaround for this problem, is this a known issue, or is it even possible to get this 2005 report to render properly in 2008?**

*NOTE: this is related to a **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313260/ssrs-exported-pdf-and-tif-report-render-differently-than-in-the-report-viewer)** that I previously asked here, and is based on this **[MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/f4d218ef-023c-40a1-8658-266a9bf8ab0d)** started by a coworker. This question is not the same as my previous question, as I'd like to see things work properly in with a 2005 report. If it's not possible, that would be good to know, as it would indicate that we need to upgrade one of our servers to SQL 2008.*

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting the table inside a rectangle (and check indeed that the table is a child of the rectangle using the Document Outline pane)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I did exactly the opposite of what is suggested in the other answers here...My table was already inside the rectangle, and it was still shifting to next page. So I removed the rectangle, and it seems to be working without any issues now!

Weird..But may be it all depends on the over all layout of the report or something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a few problems in PDF Export and most of them were solved when I placed the Table within a Rectangle. That would be worth trying !

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS 2005 Report Viewer WinForms control (ver. 8.0.50727.42)
I got similar problem.

The problem occur when I try to put some text before Table (to display as Report header).
By adding this report header, the first page available height is less than others page height.
When the rows of table exceed to fit on the first page but can fit on the second page, the whole table move to second page and the first page leave blank with report header only.
But when the rows of table exceed to fit on first page and also exceed to fit on second page, the table display on the first page as normal.
If first page and other pages have the same available height, the problem not occur.

I think this is effect of KeepTogether option.  But I already set it to False.
I try both True/False KeepTogether option,  same result.  May be KeepTogether option of Table control is not working at all.